# What type of sand is under my flagstone pavers?

Tags: pavers

I also have this question:
[Replacing pavers with grass, what do I do with the sand?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6076/replacing-pavers-with-grass-what-do-i-do-with-the-sand)

See attached photos, the brick like piece in the second photo near the shovel tip can be crumbled (with effort) in my hand.   Is it possible there is some concrete mixed with this sand, or is it just compacted so tightly that it takes on a brick like form?   Should I heed the previous advice and just mix the sand with the underlying topsoil and add some compost?

[image: zoomed_out]
[image: corner-2]
[image: corner-1]
[image: corner-steps]

Comment: Its really hard to talk from the photos but poly sand will clump but breaks up when not compacted. Since I don't see grad growing that would be my guess.

Comment: @EdBeal it looks like polymeric sand is usually used in between pavers, but based on the definitions of this sand that I find on the internet, it does seem it might have been used as a bedding for under my flagstones.   If thats the case, I assume that I should NOT mix it in with the soil and instead just do the heavy lifting of getting rid of it?

Comment: I would agree but this is the best advice I could think of so just left as a comment

Answer (score 1):

I took a sample to the local landscape supply store and they said it was most likely base rock topped with concrete sand that has decomposed over the years.  The reason it clumps is because soil is now mixed in with the rock (even though not visible).    A friend suggested it might be decomposed granite, but the supply store said DG wouldn't clump.